# Unable to include a lottie-player tag with .wrapAll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lottie

On this code each time there is an `h2` on `article` I take all of the content from the `h2` till the next `h2` and wrap it on a `section`.

```
<article>
 <h2>Lottie Files</h2>
 <div class='lottie-wrapper>
   <lottie-player src='' background="transparent" speed="1"></lottie-player>
  </div>
</article>
```

```
$('article h2').each(function () {
  $(this).nextUntil('h2').addBack().wrapAll('<section />')
})
```

But for some reason if there is the `<lottie-player>` tag, the code removes it from the DOM.

It only happens when I include lottieFiles interactivity script in conjunction with the above snippet

`https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity@latest/dist/lottie-interactivity.min.js`

This is happening on WordPress only on a simple html is not a problem.

If I remove a parent div called `.lottie-wrapper` from the wrap then it works, but not just calling the `lottie-player` tag directly

```
$('article h2').each(function () {
  $(this)
    .nextUntil('h2')
    .addBack()
    .not('.lottie-wrapper')
    .wrapAll('<section />')
})
```

But of course I want the lottie-player inside

Comment: Can you produce a working snippet to reproduce your problem? Or enough "*[mcve]*" code that we might be able to reproduce that problem ourselves?

Comment: I tried to reproduce here, but I cannot replicate it, I am actually doing it on WordPress, there it does happen whenever I have the interactivity script on and that snippet

Answer (score 0):

This was pretty bizarre, it only happened on WordPress and only when I use the script

`https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js`

Together with the jQuery `wrapAll()`. I fixed it by using an older version of the script `https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@0.4.0/dist/lottie-player.js`